# How to import a config file variable, but use a different separator?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-16.04

First, `source` and `.` are not working as I'm using a different kind of separator, which is something like.

I have tried several methods I can google, but didn't have any luck so far.
I managed to print out all the variables and values correctly, but I can't store it as a variable in this bash process.

What I want:

At end of the bash process when I "echo $HUA_IP:"
it should give me "192.168.0.1" as per the config.cf file.

File config.cf:

```
  "HUA_PASSWORD": "admin",
  "HUA_IP": "192.168.0.1"
```

While my bash file is:

```
#!/bin/bash

configFile="/opt/config.cf"
# config="`cat $configFile`"
# echo $config
# source $configFile
# echo $var1
# conf="";

while read var value
do
    # export "$var"="$value"
    var="${var%:*}"
    var="${var//\"/}"
    var="${var//[\}\{]/}"
    value="${value//\"/}"
    value="${value//,/}"
    # echo "var :'"$var"'"
    # echo "value :'"$value"'"

    if [ !$var = "" ]
    then
        # "$var"="$value"
        # eval $var=$value
        export "$var"="$value"
    fi

done < $configFile

echo $HUA_IP:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
while read -r line; do
    line=${line//\"/}
    declare -x "${line/: /=}"
done<config.cf
echo "$HUA_IP"
```

When this code is run, the output is:

```
192.168.0.1
```

#### How it works

The key here is that `declare`, which is a bash builtin, allows you to use a bash variable to create and assign another variable.   As a simple example:

```
$ x="a=b";  declare -x "$x"; echo "$a"
b
```

Now, let's apply this to your input file:

- `while read -r line; do`

  This starts a loop reading one line of input at a time.
- `line=${line//\"/}`

  This removes all double-quotes from the input line.
- `declare -x "${line/: /=}"`

  This replaces `:` with `=` in line and then creates a variable using declare.

  The `-x` option tells bash to export the variable that is declared.
- `done <config.cf`

  This tells the loop to get its stdin from `config.cf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, even if it could be not the best approach, is working if you change your `if` condition. The correct way is:

```
#...
if [ ! -z $var  ]
then
    # "$var"="$value"
    # eval $var=$value
    export "$var"="$value"
fi
```